# MySql query doesn't return the expected data

Tags: c#, mysql

```
"select * from clinic_app_database.appointment_details1 where ' " + 
 this.txtCView.SelectedItem + " ' = ' " + 
 this.txt_givenID.Text + "';";
```

i written this query using mysql workbench .. C# platform

Am inserting combobox value and textbox value at a time but am not getting the ans.

```
select * from tablename where (here am using combobox for value) = textbox;
```

please give me correct syntax if anybody knows

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `txtCView.SelectedItem` to the query, instead of passing it's value.
Also, the extra spaces that you are adding at the start and at the end of the values are modifying the string.
Try this:

```
"select * from clinic_app_database.appointment_details1 where '" + 
 this.txtCView.SelectedItem.Value + "' = '" + this.txt_givenID.Text + "';";
```

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\DELL\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CMS003\CMS003\Form1.cs 126 122 CMS003

Comment: Is your `txtCView` not an asp.net dropdown control?

Comment: What type of control is `txtCView`?

Comment: "select * from clinic_app_database.appointment_details1 where " + 
 this.txtCView.SelectedItem.Value + " = '" + this.txt_givenID.Text + "';";   _ this is the answer i got it